# Text not overlapping image css

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my text isn't overlapping the image. I see the text just below the image.

```
<div className="row location-row location nopadding justify-content-center">
    <div className="col-md-4 location-padding">
          <img className="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src={("./Components/Images/Pula.jpg")} />
          <h2><span className="badge badge-warning">Pula</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-4 location-padding">
        <img className="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src={("./Components/Images/Liznjan.jpg")} />
         <h2><span className="badge badge-warning">Liznjan</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.location-padding {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.location-padding h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
}
.location-row {
    margin: 0% 12.5% 0% 12.5%;
}
```

What I get:
[image]

Comment: Seems to work ? https://jsfiddle.net/z843qf1w/

Comment: You probably have another html or css that create this issue, the code you provided works fine

Comment: @For me not, I will upload the image

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov, hmm I will check for it now

Comment: @GigaMeta try to add z-index: 10; to your h2 tag just in case.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynow Oh yes, that worked now..

Comment: Add `z-index: 1;` with `h2`. `.location-padding h2{position: absolute;left: 10px;top: 20px;z-index: 1;}`

Comment: @GigaMeta after adding z-index? if yes please tick my answer as green please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your h2 tag, by adding z-index property like this:

```
.location-padding h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use z-index:

```
.location-padding h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```